# DataGridCheckBoxColumn IsReadOnly property binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I would like to have the checkbox column in my datagrid enabled/disabled for each row depending on a value in a collection. I have an ObservableCollection called AccountComponents that is a collection of a class called AccountComponent which has a boolean property called Enabled. I've tried binding the Enabled property to IsReadOnly and IsEnabled with no luck.

Here's XAML where I tried a DataGridCheckBoxColumn-

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" IsReadOnly="{Binding AccountComponents/Enabled}"/>
```

Here's XAML where I tried a DataGridTemplateColumn-

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="False"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Any help figuring this out is much appreciated.

Comment: What messages are you getting from the Output window?

Comment: It's the same for *any* property on *any* type of column. Abstract your problem, search, find the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there is no need to specify a `CellEditingTemplate` when just using CheckBoxes. CheckBoxes themself are "editable/checkable". So remove that `CellEditingTemplate` since this makes no sense.

Have you tried to bind the `IsEnabled` property of the CheckBox directly to your `Enabled` property of your `AccountComponent` in the CellTemplate (like you did it in the CellEditingTemplate)? This should solve your problem.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"
                      IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you Markus that worked. Can you tell me why binding to the IsReadOnly property on the DataGridCheckBoxColumn wouldn't work?

Comment: I haven’t tested it, but your Binding-Expression with 'AccountComponents/Enabled' looks suspicious. This is normally used for Master/Detail scenarios where in that case you already have your detail. My first attempt would be IsReadOnly="{Binding Enabled}"

Comment: I thought it looked weird as well but that is the syntax VS created when I picked Enabled from the databinding popup window. I tried your suggesstion but it didn't work. I guess I will stick with the datatemplatecolumn. Thanks for your help.