# How to set DataGrid column property same as binding value?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

How come I can set my binding for my DataGrid like this:

```
 <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Include" Binding="{Binding isSelected}"/>
```

But when I add the "IsReadOnly"

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Include" IsReadOnly="{Binding isSelected}" Binding="{Binding isSelected}"/>
```

it gives me an warning on "IsReadOnly" that no datacontext is found.

Comment: DataGridColumns have no DataContext. That `Binding="{Binding ...` works because it's resolved inside the celltemplate of each cell, which has the data context of the item/row it belongs to and which is set by the ItemsSource property usually (or Items).
If you want DataBinding for real DataColumn properties (like IsReadOnly) you need to reference your viewmodel via the `Source`, `ElementName` properties of the Binding.
`RelativeSource` won't work either because the "governing FrameworkElement" is missing, because the column is not part of the visual tree.

Comment: IsReadOnly refers to all items, so the corresponding data context is one level highter than Binding, which refers to the specific objects in your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsReadOnly` refers to all items, so the corresponding data context is one level highter than `Binding`, which refers to the specific objects in your table.
So you need to define the cell template manually like this to disable some cells specifically:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      IsEnabled="{Binding isSelected}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178073/datagridcheckboxcolumn-isreadonly-property-binding), which basically describes the same problem.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't a column at all really. A datagrid...column is logical and used to create cells but not really a thing itself. So you can't make it readonly, it ain't there.

Comment: The accepted answer is not the only way to do this. You could define a datatrigger in a cellstyle for a checkbox column

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue with Element style. Whether this element can possibly be returned as a hit test result from some portion of its rendered content.

Try adding `ElementStyle` element to your `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`

```
 <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Include" IsReadOnly="{Binding isSelected}"  ElementStyle="{StaticResource ReadOnlyCheckBoxStyle}" Binding="{Binding isSelected}"/>
```

And the following style

```
<Style x:Key="ReadOnlyCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
      <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/> 
</Style>
```

Comment: This answer is confusing an not right at all. The reason is that the context of IsReadOnly and Binding is simply not the same.